# mysqli_query is not displaying any results

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve data matching a specific email from a MySQL table. There are 2 records associated with this email, but nothing is printed on my screen.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdrive');


$sql = mysqli_query($conn, 
        'SELECT * FROM products_bought
        where email = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, "a@gmail.com").'"'
    );
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    $fullname = $row['fullname'];
    ?>
    <p><?php echo $fullname; ?></p>
    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: What do you get if you check the various mysqli calls for failures?

Comment: In your query line, right before the semicolon, add this: 'or die(mysqli_error($conn));' this will stop execution if the query fails. Also, inside the while loop, add this: 'print_r($row);' this will print all values of the array.

Comment: @Paul i am getting as usual result

Comment: @MattClark no error .but nothing is showing in screen

Comment: Can you try assigning the whole query string to a variable, and then echo that variable before you execute the query? My guess now is that the query is not coming out exactly as you expect it to, so it is not returning any rows. Another thought, add the same or die statement after your mysqli_connect, to ensure you are getting a valid connection. Apologies for speed and typos, i am on mobile.

Comment: echo $sql->num_rows() to check if something selected ot echo sql and run it on your php myadmin to check if it is constructed properly.

Comment: You got the `$conn` variable , I mean your db connection is established ?? Go step by step

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
<p><?php $fullname; ?></p>
```

This is not actually outputting a value, you can either use `echo` to output the value of the variable, or use PHP short tags like so,

```
<p><?= $fullname; ?></p>
```

Or the long way using echo

```
<p><?php echo $fullname; ?></p>
```

Comment: but yet not getting the result :( `<p><?php echo $fullname; ?></p>`

Comment: Then you have another issue as well. Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 0):

To Check that you are connected to DB or not please try below code and test, also check that are you getting data in `mysqli_fetch_array($sql)` using `print_r`

```
    <?php

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdrive');

    if(mysqli_errno($conn))
    {

        echo"sum error";
    }
    else
    {
      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, "a@gmail.com");
      $sql = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM products_bought where email = "'.$email.'"'
        );
         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
          $fullname = $row['fullname'];
        ?>
        <p><?php echo $fullname; ?></p>
        <?php
         }
    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the problems came from, but i want to help you a bit :

```
<?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'testdrive');
   $sql = mysqli_query($conn,'SELECT * FROM products_bought
    where email = "'.mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, "a@gmail.com").'"');

   if($sql->num_rows > 0){ // Check existence of the data that received
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        $fullname = $row['fullname'];
        echo "<p>".$fullname."</p>"; // Why just echoing it in one <?PHP ?>
      }
   } else {
      // If no data sent. then check your db, cause the problems was in your db
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

the select `database` please try

```
   $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    $db = mysqli_select_db('testdrive');
```

Comment: `mysqli_connect` is enough to do that ! ... he was selected `testdrive` as the db

Comment: sorry i missing this little change @MichaelAntonio

Answer (score 0):

Please  check once your database connection done successfully ?

mysqli_connect(DATABASE_HOST, DATABASE_USERNAME, DATABASE_PASSWORD,DATABASE_NAME) or die('Could not connect with server.');

because query you have written is right.